# good old fashion ie7 width and clear issues (blast from the past) with demo

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am just in the middle of creating a highly flexible sass/grid framework and I have run into some odd IE7 browser issues that I dont fully understand why they're happening.

**The fiddle is here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjacob/mbvw5/

(easiest way to test for most people is to run IE7 mode using IE dev bar in IE9/IE10)

**Code for ref** (and cos stack overflow wont post this q with just a fiddle link):

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col1">col1</div>
        <div class="col2">row width == 398</div>
        <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container2">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col1">col1</div>
        <div class="col2">row width == 400</div>
        <div class="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">col1</div>
        <div class="col2">row width == 400</div>
        <div class="col3">col3</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#container1 { margin:0 auto; width:398px; }
#container2 { margin:0 auto; width:400px; }
.row { background:red; width:100%; }
.col1 { float:left; width:13%; margin:1%; background:pink; }
.col2 { float:left; width:63%; margin:1%; background:yellow; }
.col3 { float:left; width:18%; margin:1%; background:cyan; }

.clear { clear:both; }
.clearfix { zoom:1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { display:table; content:""; }
.clearfix:after { clear:both; }
```

There are 2 very distinct things going on here that I would love people's opinions on:

1. Why does the new micro clearfix not work/show margin/show red background like the good old fashion clear both div found at bottom of fiddle?
2. Why when the container is 400px the cols are fine, yet using a container of 398px pushes the third column down and wraps it on new line?

Note on IE8+ and all other good browsers this isnt an issue. Im sure IE6 is affected also but I cant test.

Ad.

Comment: It looks like it's a rounding bug with the percentages, setting the with to 200px also works.

Comment: changing the width to 62.9 seems to work:


.col2 { float:left; width:62.9%; margin:1%; background:yellow; }

Comment: Found a great article actually that helped me fix this in sass: http://tylertate.com/blog/2012/01/05/subpixel-rounding.html now I just need to work out why IE7 clear/clearfix work differently